# error Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.4 and maatwebsite 2.1.0

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"
I'm using laravel 5.4, php 5.6 and maatwebsite 2.1.0
to get excel file and here is the code

```
function excel()
    {
        $tebtom = Tebtom::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
        $tebtom_array[] = array('رقم الموضوع', 'إسم الراسل', 'رقم الهاتف', 'البريد الإلكترونى', 'رقم العضوية', 'المرفق', 'القصة', 'تاريخ الإضافة');
        foreach ($tebtom as $tebtomItem)
        {
            $tebtom_array[] = array(
                'رقم الموضوع' => $tebtomItem->id,
                'إسم الراسل' => $tebtomItem->Name,
                'رقم الهاتف' => $tebtomItem->mobile,
                'البريد الإلكترونى' => $tebtomItem->email,
                'رقم العضوية' => $tebtomItem->membership,
                'المرفق' => $tebtomItem->attach,
                'القصة' => $tebtomItem->story,
                'تاريخ الإضافة' => $tebtomItem->created_at
            );
        }
        Excel::create('بيانات المواضيع', function($excel) use ($tebtom_array){
            $excel->setTitle('بيانات المواضيع');
            $excel->sheet('بيانات المواضيع', function($sheet) use ($tebtom_array){
                $sheet->fromArray($tebtom_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: A line number, expected output and solutions that you've tried would be very helpful.

Comment: @rpm192 ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object in TebtomController.php line 36 which is this line                 'رقم الموضوع' => $tebtomItem->id,

Comment: Can you try removing `->toArray()` and see what that outputs?

Comment: @rpm192 now it's working and I got the excel file exported but I don't know what I'm missing after removing toArray anyway thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the `->toArray()` because you're fetching the query results as an array which will not allow you to get the individual properties using `->id` for example, thus throwing an error.

Removing it will fetch the results as a collection which will allow you to iterate over them using the `foreach` loop.

`$tebtom = Tebtom::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`